# How to make Karate Tests run as a service

Tags: karate

I have implemented karate tests and they run fine locally. Now I want to run it as a service meaning expose few rest endpoints e.g /ServiceA and it will take the request and trigger specific karate tests. The whole process will be async as multiple team can submit test request and show the execution report by calling GET endpoint.
Any pointer on how this can be achieved?

Comment: @ptrthomas any suggestion on how to address above problem.

Comment: if the linked question does not answer your question, please assume this is not directly supported. it is up to you and your knowledge of java, etc. and please focus on 1.0 https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/751